# How can I get a point on a sphere knowing the radius and the rotation?

Tags: geometry, spheres

I have the two rotation angles, the center and the radius of a sphere.
Is there a way to get the point on the sphere intersected by my radius?

[image]

Comment: you should only have two rotation angles, what's the third?

Comment: You will need $$r,\theta,\phi$$

Comment: @sortai you are right, sorry. Dr. Sonnhard, Could you, please, elaborate more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $r$ is the radius, $\theta$ is the angle from the z axis, and $\phi$ is the angle around the z axis, away from the x axis (going counterclockwise if seen from the region of space $z>0$), then $x$, $y$, and $z$ are:
$$x = r*sin(\theta)*cos(\phi)$$
$$y = r*sin(\theta)*sin(\phi)$$
$$z = r*cos(\theta)$$

Comment: for more information, take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system